# Wordpress get_posts not showing all the posts

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following code:

```
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;

$staff = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'=> 'staff'));
$i = 0;
echo 'Staff number: '.count($staff);
```

and it echoes 'Staff number: 6' but if I run the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = 'staff'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

it shows me the 7 members of the staff... any ideas on how to retrieve the 7 staff members by get_posts()?

Thank you

Comment: Are all 7 posts published? Can you see them in your dashboard? Perhaps one of them is a revision

Comment: I have checked the post status and everything is published, if I have the posts A, B, C, D, E, F and G, it only shows A, B, C, D, E and F. If I change the status to 'revision' in C it shows, A, B, D, E, F and G. Always 6...

Answer (score 0):

It was a limitation of the Wordpress Theme that I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `'posts_per_page' => -1` to print all the posts. For example?

```
$all_posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
             'posts_per_page' => -1
        ) );
```